# Find string with case sentence structure (UC lc $word)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, uppercase

I need to find all records structured like this

```
Anyinitcapcaseword anylowercaseword $specificstring
```

e.g.

UC lc $software = Database modeling software

I'm not sure how to set up Regex to do that other then the basics (where Regex)

Any thoughts appreciated

In same vein also need to find this structure

Boundary scan description language BSDL

Initcap lowercase1-N UC

where letters in UC equal # of previous words. I don't mind doing manually e.g

Init lc lc [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]

Init lc lc lc [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]

since there are a finite # of cases

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE columnName LIKE '%[A-Z]*\s[a-z]*\s$[a-zA-Z]*%'
```